# Why collections shouldn't be used for unbounded data?

Tags: cassandra

From Cassandra docs:

> A collection is appropriate if the data for collection storage is limited.     If the data has unbounded growth potential, like messages sent or sensor events registered every second, do not use collections.
> Instead, use a table with a compound primary key where data is stored in the clustering columns.

I'm trying to understand why this is the case.

Let's say I have a messaging app and instead of using `PrimaryKey(chatId, timestamp, messageId)` I'd use something like `PrimaryKey(chatId)` with `messages` column where `messages` is a list of messages in a chat.

Answer (score 1):

Understand what? You want to add the entire chat history i.e. all the messages in a single column of a single row? Would you do that in a regular sql db? No - there would be a table where each message is its own row

Apart from the fact that you will lose all ability to query the messages in the proposed schema - just the size of that one key would balloon up to the point that the ops required for the cluster will become a nightmare